# How to set headers in express routes nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I am working on express js and in the incoming POST request, the username and password are present in the body of the request, I want to implement routing such that an authorisation header can be added to the incoming req object

My routing is as follows :

```
router.route('/token')
  .post(function(req,res,next){
    if(req.body.client_id){
      //set headers for authentication, e.g "Authorization":"Basic dskvnksnsnjsnvsnlvnsd"
      next();      
    }

  },authController.isClientAuthenticated,oauth2Controller.token);
```

Comment: Set them in `req.headers`

Answer (score 1):

You can add headers by using the `req.headers` property:
`req.headers.authorization = 'Basic ...'`

Note that there is a `res.headersSent` property, which can be used to determine if headers have already been sent to the client, otherwise you will encounter an error.